# Car having trouble starting but everthing else works even without key

Tags: pontiac, grand-am

97 pontiac grand am se v6, a while ago my car did not start, I guess it was the ignition switch. So it got repaired but then the other day it wouldn't start. And it would not shift out of park at all, but when I went to take it to the same shop everything worked but I took it in anyway. When I got it back it ran fine for a day, then my radio, wippers, defroster and dome lights would not work so I checked the fuses and replaced one and it started and everything works even without the key. Now its having trouble starting it starts in about 1 in 30 trys. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does the engine turn over but not start or do you turn the key and nothing happens?

Comment: It turns over but will not start

Comment: So it stoped starting agian i think part of it might be the cold but when it does start you will hear 3 fast ticks if i dont hear that it will not start does anyone know what that might be?

Comment: "works even without the key." could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Does the vehicle have any aftermarket accessories? [Alarm (factory?) / Radio / Disco-ball / etc.]

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking at the steering column wiring. I think you have a pinched,cut, chafed etc wire. The fact that you blew a fuse and the accessories work without the key leads me to believe you have power being applied when it shouldn't be and not being applied when it should be. Be careful about random probing in the column as you can inadvertantly discharge the airbag.

Comment: I hope the airbag dont go off and its starting fine now every time but ill keep you guys posted

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a charging system problem or a parasitic drain on the battery.

Check the parasitic drain by following [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdIKNnwEjIs). If none found you may need a new alternator/battery.

Comment: Batterys good and no power drain